# How to deal with taxable income from discharge of student loan?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I received a Total Permanent Disability discharge of my student loan debt.  This created HUGE taxable income for me.  How can I deal with that tax liability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a large student loan discharged as well a few years ago. But there's a form for that!

You'll need to file Form 982 to declare your insolvency (basically, your assets minus debts, including the one being discharged). if your debts are more than your assets, you don't owe tax on it. You will only pay tax on the portion that you are solvent for.

[Additional info](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p4681/)

Answer (score 6):

Please visit this [link on the IRS site](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Tips-for-Taxpayers-Who-Can%27t-Pay-Their-Taxes-on-Time).

Having said this I had a friend in a very similar situation as yours.  You are in a situation I am assuming that you do not have a lot of income, this was an unforeseen event (you couldn't plan for 5 years to save for the student loans being discharged), and you are in otherwise in good standing with the IRS.

My friend won a very expensive trip (30K) while they were in college.

Here is what I would suggest:

1. Call the IRS.  Have them open a case on your situation and get advise from their helpdesk.  Please keep very formal notes on your conversations - who you talked to and what they said.  In many states you can legally record these conversations.
2. Don't even think about putting this on your credit card until that is your last option.  The IRS mentions this because it is easy for them.  The end goal is you paying the bill off in installments.  If the IRS thinks that you putting this on a credit card is doable or you are thinking about it, they won't be inclined to help you and might just say no when asking for installments or deferrals.
3. Make a substantial good faith payment.  Include a note that is pretty honest about your finances and how that this payment is a good part of your savings.   A partial payment is key.  I would need to know more about your income and finances to offer a specific example. The IRS wants to see that you aren't just trying to get out of paying.  Even if this is 1/20th of the amount, they will more likely help if they see a payment.
4. Work with their people and file a Form 9465-FS.  This should set up a payment plan for the due taxes.  Most of the time they want things paid back in 5 years.  The interest rate charged to my friend was a little over 6%, so far better than putting it on a credit card.

If you had a life changing event and it looks like paying the taxes back isn't ever feasible this is a totally different game.  First get ready for a complete audit of your life.  The IRS will ask for bank statements, credit card statements, a complete spreadsheet of expenses by category, your assets, and a look at your complete living conditions.  They will certainly have a field agent visit you too (maybe many times).  The IRS has amounts that they will allow for people to spend on certain things (food, cars, home, clothing, whatever).

If you are over their baseline amounts they will simply reject your inability to pay and either go after your assets or take you to court.  If you are truly in a dire situation and will probably never have the ability to repay the IRS will reach a settlement with you.  There is no use for them to spend a bunch of money on money they will never recover.

The key for you is two-fold.  Make sure that the IRS understands that you know that you owe them money and then also to be honest with your financial situation.